# Using react-router with react portals?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm implementing an app with plenty of tables that works with the react-router perfectly, reading the URL query etc.

Now I need to put one of the tables inside a modal (I'm using [AntUI Modal](https://ant.design/components/modal/) component for this purpose). From this table I can change the URL query in the browser by using `history`:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export const history = createHistory()
...
history.push({ search: 'my search here' });
```

The problem is that the URL changes are not visible for the table inside the modal. I've tried wrapping the component in `withRouter` HOC but it did not help, so I assume that the problem is that the modal is not laying inside the `<Router>` component.

Can it be easily fixed? Or maybe my whole thought process is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is going to face a similar issue - just pass the router props (`match`, `location`, `history`) directly to the children of `Modal` component.

Comment: Have you found a solution to using `<Link/>` directly without the [fallback of manually pushing to history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357366/how-to-use-link-react-router-inside-mui-popover?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment101202045_57357366)?