# How to use Link react-router inside MUI Popover?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have my entry point `index.js` with `Router` from react router 5 defined
(not a duplicate of [You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640280/you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router)):

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

But I still have the famous *You should not use `<Link>` outside a `<Router>`* error on my component using Material UI `Popover`:

```
const InterventionMarker = ({ marker, history }) => {

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const handleClick = event => setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  const handleClose = () => setAnchorEl(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return (
    <MarkerWithLabel
      onClick={handleClick}
      ...other-props
    >
      <div>
        {marker.label}
        <Popover
          id={marker.label}
          open={open}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          onClose={handleClose}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'top',
            horizontal: 'center',
          }}
          transformOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'center',
          }}
        >
          {marker.interventions.map(i =>
            <Link history={history} component={RouterLink} to={`/interventions/${i.id}`}>
              {i.number} - {i.name}
            </Link>
          )}
        </Popover>
      </div>
    </MarkerWithLabel>
  );
};

export default withRouter(React.memo(InterventionMarker));
```

I tried to pass `history` prop (via `withRouter` HOC) to the `Popover` component (idea from [Using react-router with react portals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771502/using-react-router-with-react-portals)).

I tried to add `Router` tag to my component but I don't really like this option even if it seems to work.

Any other ideas to enable `RouterLink` inside `Popover` component ?

Comment: I think you going to have to manually `push` the new location using `history.push(/interventions/${i.id})` instead of using the built in `Link` component. can you try with a button just for testing ? ```<button onClick={() => history.push(`/interventions/${i.id}`)}>Test</button>```

Comment: I will go with your solution for now.